# Could not access user defined functions in Spark

Tags: apache-spark

I found I could not access the function of mine in a Spark job, the "sbt package" has not problem, but when run the program by spark-submit, I got:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:       
scala.Predef$.ArrowAssoc(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
at TF$$anonfun$TF1$1$2.apply(tf.scala:23)
```

The program is quite simple:

```
import ...

object TF{

def main(args:Array[String]) {
     val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("TF")
     val sc=new SparkContext(conf)

   def TF1(list: List[String]) = { 
      ...
   }   

   val aaa=List("import", "org", "apache", "spark", "SparkContext")
   val tfs=TF1(aaa)
   tfs.foreach(println)
 }

}
```

Also tested that to put the TF1 function outside main() does not work either. Any suggestions how to access a user-defined function in main() in Spark? Thanks!

Comment: How are you building the program and what are the arguments you are supplying to spark submit?

Comment: I doubt your problem is with not finding your `TF1` method, it complains about not finding the `Predef#ArrowAssoc(s: Object): Object` method. Which is certainly not in `Predef`, though it has an implicit class [`ArrowAssoc`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.7/src/library/scala/Predef.scala#L247). So your problem is in the -unshown- `TF1` method. Could you please share it (where you use `->` or `→` between two values to form a tuple)?

Comment: The TF1 function is as:

Comment: The TF1 function is as: def TF1(list: List[String]) = { list.groupBy(x => x).map {elem =>  elem._1 -> elem._2.length}}. Tested the function itself works fine, just confused why it could not be found. The program is built with "sbt package" successfully and submit with "spark-submit --class TF ./target/scala-2.11/tf_2.11-1.0.jar mesos://mesos-cluster:5050"